# Regex match line with all words starting in uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to create a regex pattern that matches a line where all the words begin with uppercase letters, regardless of length. It must also account for any number of equals signs ('=') being on either side.

For example matches:

```
==This Would Match==
===I Like My Cats===
====Number Of Equals Signs Does Not Matter===
=====Nor Does Line Length Etc.=====
```

Non-matches:

```
==This would not regardless of its length==
===Nor would this match, etc===
```

How do I write this pattern?

Comment: Would ==This ==Match

Comment: Please show what you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matches your desired results:

```js
var test = [
  "==This Would Match==",
  "===I Like My Cats===",
  "====Number Of Equals Signs Does Not Matter===",
  "=====Nor Does Line Length Etc.=====",
  "==This would not regardless of its length==",
  "===Nor would this match, etc==="
]

var reg = /=*([A-Z]\w*\W*)+=*/g;

console.log(test.map(t => t.match(reg) == t));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match one or more equals signs at either side like `=+`.

To match words that begin with a capital letter could start with `[A-Z]` followed by `\w` one or more times. If you want to match more characters than `\w`, you could create a character class `[\w.]` to add matching a dot for example.

This pattern would match between equals sign(s) zero or more times a word that starts with an uppercase character followed by a whitespace, and ends with a word that starts with an uppercase character:

[`^=+(?:[A-Z]\w* )*(?:[A-Z][\w.]+)=+$`](https://regex101.com/r/6OfqGW/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "==This Would Match==",
  "===I Like My Cats===",
  "====Number Of Equals Signs Does Not Matter===",
  "=====Nor Does Line Length Etc.=====",
  "==This would not regardless of its length==",
  "===Nor would this match, etc===",
  "=aaaa="
];
let pattern = /^=+(?:[A-Z]\w* )*(?:[A-Z][\w.]+)=+$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^=*[A-Z][^ ]*( [A-Z][^ ]*)*=*$
```

It allows for any number (including 0) of `=` signs on either side and requires every word to start with a capital letter.

The `*` quantifier means 0 or more times.

`[^ ]` is a negated character class, meaning it matches anything except a space.

You can try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ejku6j/1).